# 1990s (?) Animated sci-fi cartoon. Search for Indiana Jones lookalike

Tags: story-identification, aliens, cartoon

I'm trying to recall the name of an animated sci-fi cartoon I rented out of the public library during the late 1990s. I can only remember a couple of scenes/themes;

- It involved aliens
- The plot, I believe, revolved around searching for this one important guy, he was wearing a trench coat and brown hat in the style of Indiana Jones.
- The main characters I can't narrow down but it did involve a little girl whom was the daughter to one of the characters
- Towards the end of the film, the man they were searching for had an imposter that looked exactly like him, but was an alien in disguise. The two of them had a little fight where the real one was victorious and unveiled the alien imposter. The imposter then killed himself I believe with some sort of capsule, twitching on the ground. I don't remember why the alien was disguised as the missing person, but it might have been framing him for something.
- After this scene there was something where a large flying creature came and snatched one of the characters away (another alien I think) and one of the other characters started shooting at the creature in a vain attempt to save the guy. The guy wasn't really trustworthy to begin with, as I can recall.
- one of the main characters (who I believe is the father to the little girl) was a rather tall and built man with blonde hair. He might have had glasses on but my memory can't recall. (UPDATE: Did not have blonde hair, had black hair and was tall and thin).

Comment: Was it one movie? Not a serial?

Comment: Set in space, on Earth? Other aliens, or just the impostor? Animation style Western or anime?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not exactly sure if it was a one-time movie or part of a series. I'm inclined to say it was a movie.  It was set in space for sure, took place on different planets. There were other aliens other than the imposter. The animation style was Western for sure because of how fluid the animation seemed and the depiction of the characters' faces.

Answer (score 7):

Update: I just found it by accident while doing some more research. The moment I saw this image memories came flooding back.

[image: Image I stumbled upon]

The name of the film is *The Mystery of the Third Planet* (or The Secret of the Third Planet), which was a 1981 Russian cult classic, released in the U.S. in 1985.

If anyone would like to relive this old childhood, clips can be found on youtube: [Mystery Of The Third Planet](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2TAmISW76Rk)

Thanks for the time everyone took to help narrow down the name of this old sci-fi classic.

Comment: You should probably accept this as an answer. Also thanks for reviving some good memories, gonna watch it again as soon as I can! ;)